# htaccess help - migrating site with multiple rules

Tags: .htaccess

I am doing a site migration and I want to know if there is a way to apply multiple rules in httacess and the proper order so that if more than one rule matches, the page will be redirect properly.  Here is the scenario:

1. Some pages will have exact match redirects (e.g., www.a.com/page1.html to www.b.com/page1_new.html). I assume I can use Redirect 301 for these
2. I have a wordpress blog on site a that is going to site b, but in different sub-directories. So I need to redirect everything in www.a.com/blog/ to www.b.com/wordpress/ .  I need help with the syntax on this one.
3. A catch all redirect for anything that is left, which would redirect anything not matching 1 or 2.  For these, filenames would be the same, for example, redirecting www.a.com/page1.html to www.b.com/page1.html, or www.a.com/dir1/3.html to www.b.com/dir1/3.html . I think I can figure this one out too.

So really I need to know if I can put the rules in .htaccess in the order above, if that is how they will be executed, and also the proper syntax for option 2 (I've seen both RewriteCond/RewriteRule & RedirectMatch suggested).

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

`1.` and `2.` you will have to do on the server of `www.a.com` anyways, and the `Redirect` directive should be enough for both of those.

And `3.` has to happen on the server of `www.b.com`, where I would not recommend to redirect anywhere, but just let the `ErrorDocument 404` take care of that – because: If some content is not available any more, the user should be notified of that – and not automatically be redirected to the home page or something, at least IMHO. (No problem with offering him alternative choices and maybe a search form *in* the 404 response document.) And search engines will like this better also, because it helps them to quicker remove dead links. Although for that the response code `410 Gone` would be more approriate. So if you can distinguish between old (re-written) URLs that just don’t exist *any more*, and “real” 404s where the requested URL has never had anything to deliver before, that would be the way to go – `410` for old, dead URLs, and `404` for anything else that does not exists. (To differ between those two cases, a 404 handling script that checks the requested URL against f.e. an array containing old link URLs could be a simple solution.) If that’s not possible, answering just all “not found” requests with `410 Gone` should not be harmful either.

Comment: I don't know if I explained myself very well with #3.  If I do NOT have a generic redirect on site A, then if someone visits www.a.com/page1.html, isn't it just going to show www.a.com/page1.html?  In other words, there is no redirection for that set-up in 1 or 2, so setting something up on server B is not going to matter, because the user will never get to site B.

Comment: As I said, the `Redirect` directive should be enough to redirect `www.a.com/everything` to `www.b.com/everything`, no matter if `/everything` exists/existed on `www.a.com` or not. If you’re not familiar with how `Redirect` works, please consult the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Redirects in 1 & 2 are for a single file in the root directory, and a single sub-directory. They do not take care of any other sub-directories/folders, nor do they take care of the rest of the files in the root directory. So I still think I need a third entry on site A for all files/folders that do not match 1 & 2. But I do understand your point about putting something on server B to catch the redirects to pages that do not exist. Thanks.

Comment: I have it mostly working, but the syntax is still not correct on #2. It redirects the main /blog directory, but /blog/sub-dir-1/sub-dir-2/ is not working.